# Use tikz symbols various places document

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have a question probably quite simple.
Even i'm quite sure somebody had asked it before but i didn't find it...

I want to use some symbols in in different arrangements in multiple figures over a document.

for example i have this symbol.

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw (0,0) circle (2);
        \draw[fill,black!80] (120:2) -- (-120:2) -- (0:2) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to create this once with some properties like name, rotation location etc.
And use it afterwards in other figures?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

% \ctria[optional settings]{coordinate} to be used in tikz pictures
\newcommand\ctria[2][]%
  {\begin{scope}[shift={(#2)},#1]
   \draw (0,0) circle (2);
   \draw[fill,black!80] (120:2) -- (-120:2) -- (0:2) -- cycle;
   \end{scope}
  }

% \CTRIA[optional settings] to be used outside of tikz pictures
\newcommand\CTRIA[1][]{\tikz\ctria[#1]{0,0};}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \ctria{0,0}
  \ctria[rotate=30]{4,0}
  \ctria[rotate=600]{8,0}
\end{tikzpicture}

\CTRIA[scale=0.1]
\blindtext

\CTRIA[rotate=90,scale=0.1]
\blindtext
\end{document}
```